# Loader not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a loader.
For doing this I am using the following code:

```
function loadnextview() {   
      document.getElementById("savePop").style.display = 'block';
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url : url,
         data : {jid : jid},
         async : false,
         success : function(response){
              document.getElementById("savePop").style.display = "none";  

          });
}
```

This works, for me in firefox but in Chrome the loader doesn't show up. 
Only if a time out is added then the loader shows up. But I  do not want to add
a timeout as it will delay the process.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: perhaps Chrome is just too fast :)

Comment: A `setTimeout` of 10 ms wouldn't be much of a delay now, would it?

Comment: try to apply alert in your ajax success.

Comment: You need to fix up your curly braces, they don't match.

Comment: `async : false`? Kinda defeating the purpose of Ajax

Comment: @asprin: setting async to false shows the loader.. but is this correct way? Because the process is not in a synchronous fashion. I wanted this behaviour also.

Comment: The loader should show up irrespective of the value of `async`

Answer (score -1):

Use Hide() and Show() Function from JQuery, instead of Javascript Styling.

Use This JS Code for Solution.

```
function loadnextview() 
{   
      $("#savePop").show();
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url : url,
         data : {jid : jid},
         async : false,
         success : function(response){
            $("#savePop").hide();
            }
          });
}
```

Comment: if you are Testing this Code on Local Machine then you will not see the Loader because its too fast process. if you want to Test it then Comment the Line from my Function
//$("#savePop").hide();
and use it.